# PHP initializing a class while calling a function with arguments

Tags: php, class, object, arguments

In php, i would like to call the initialized properties of the class while calling function with arguments but can't seem to figure it out. Below is my source code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Task 25 NOvember 2015</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php 
class Task{
 public $name = "abc";
 public $fname = "xyz";
 public $dob = "10-9-90";
 public $country = "country";
 public $ddress = "Street";
 public $cgpa = 3;
 public $degree = "MCS";
 public $year = "2014";
 
 public function method1($arg1, $arg2, $arg3){
  $this->name = $arg1;
  $this->fname = $arg2;
  $this->dob = $arg3;
  
  return "My name is ".$this->name."  ".", and my father name is ".$this->fname;
  //i want to print the above values ... without giving in the function args 
  
  
  }
 public function method2($arg4,$arg5){
  
  
  
  
  }
 public function method3(){}
 public function method4(){}
 public function method5(){}
 
 }
 
 
   $object1 = new Task();
   
   echo $object1->method1("","","");
  
  




?>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm a new php programmer, I would like to figure out how I can make the initialized properties of the class to the function arguments that echo that initialized values when calling functions through objects of that class.

Comment: It's easier to just NOT use classes when you're doing something really simple. This isn't like java, where you HAVE to use classes. In php, you don't have to.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,,, but it,s our task in the software house ,,, i have to do this on that way ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing the initial values to empty string in you code:

```
echo $object1->method1("","","");
```

try :

```
<?php
class Task
{
    public $name = "Naveed";
    public $fname = "Zahid";
    public $dob = "10-04-1991";
    public $country = "Pakistan";
    public $ddress = "shergarh mardan kpk";
    public $cgpa = 3.83;
    public $degree = "MCS";
    public $year = "2014";

    public function method1($arg1, $arg2, $arg3) {
        $this->name = $arg1;
        $this->fname = $arg2;
        $this->dob = $arg3;

        return "My name is " . $this->name . "  " . ", and my father name is " . $this->fname;

        //i want to print the above values ... without giving in the function args


    }

    public function method2($arg4, $arg5) {
    }

    public function method3() {
    }

    public function method4() {
    }

    public function method5() {
    }
}

$object1 = new Task();

echo $object1->method1("Naveed", "Zahid", "10-04-1991");
?>
```

Or if you really need to use the initialized values, do not put arguments and do not overwrite the initial values:

```
<?php
class Task
{
    public $name = "Naveed";
    public $fname = "Zahid";
    public $dob = "10-04-1991";
    public $country = "Pakistan";
    public $ddress = "shergarh mardan kpk";
    public $cgpa = 3.83;
    public $degree = "MCS";
    public $year = "2014";

    public function method1() {
        return "My name is " . $this->name . "  " . ", and my father name is " . $this->fname;
        //i want to print the above values ... without giving in the function args
    }

    public function method2($arg4, $arg5) {
    }

    public function method3() {
    }

    public function method4() {
    }

    public function method5() {
    }
}

$object1 = new Task();

echo $object1->method1();
?>
```

Also, try to learn more about basic/advance of PHP. you can start using this link: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/ tutorialspoint help me alot when studying new language

Comment: Thank alot .. this is our task that make a class with the 8 properties ans 5 functions that have arguments and call methods(function) in method using  "&"... i need this solution

Comment: @user3719190 does this solve your problem? mark it as accepted if it is. if not, could you enhance your question above so we can help you better